# Adding and multiplying tables' data by values in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table of subtractions and divisions sorted by date:

```
tblFactors
dt            sub    divide
2014-07-01     1      1
2014-06-01     0      5
2014-05-01     2      1
2014-05-01     0      3
```

I have another table of values, sorted by date:

```
tblValues
dt             val
2014-07-05      4
2014-06-15      5
2014-05-15      21
2014-04-14      31
2014-03-15      71
```

I need to perform some sequential calculations.  For the first value in `tblFactors`, I need to subtract 1 from every `val` where `tblValues.dt < '2014-07-01'`.

Next, I need to process the second row in `tblFactors`.  There is nothing to subtract.  However, the `divide = 5` means that I need to divide every `val` by 5 where `tblValues.dt < '2014-06-01'`.  The tricky thing is that I need to do this on the modified val from the row before (divide 20 / 5, not 21 / 5).

Each row in `tblFactors` would process in this manner, giving a sequence like this:

```
                tblFactors:    Row 1        Row 2          Row 3        Row 4

Dt          Original Val    Subtract 1   Divide by 5     Subtract 2  Divide by 3
7/5/2014    4               
6/15/2014   5                    4          
5/15/2014   21                  20           4      
4/14/2014   31                  30           6           4  
3/25/2014   71                  70          14          12              4
```

This would leave me with:

```
   qryValues
    dt             val
    2014-07-05      4
    2014-06-15      4
    2014-05-15      4
    2014-04-14      4
    2014-03-15      4
```

Right now I'm doing vector multiplications over loops in `R`.  I was wondering if there was a clever way to accomplish this in the native sql.  I tried doing some aggregations but I've had limited success.

Comment: Is the "need to divide every val where tblValues.dt < '2014-07-01' by 1" a typo?

Comment: I took that out for clarity.